# how to change jquery ui input textbox background image

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, uitextfield

I have a custom image for a text field . I am using jquery mobile input textbox . I want to apply my custom image as background to the input text box. Please guide me how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the image to the background in CSS:

```
<form>
    <label for="text-1">Text input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text-1" id="text-1" value="hello world!" />
</form>

#text-1 {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1000/40/abstract/1/") !important;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1p 0 #333;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/53RGY/)**

[image: screenshot]

**UPDATE:** OP wants background on slider handle too:

Add a container around the slider to make the CSS selector easier:

```
<div id="sliderContainer">
    <label for="slider-1">Slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="0" max="100" value="50" />            
</div>
```

Apply the background to the div with class of .ui-slider-handle inside the container:

```
#sliderContainer .ui-slider-handle {
       background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/80/80/abstract/3/") !important; 
}
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/53RGY/3/)**

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: is it the same if i have change the background image for jquery mobile slider handle?

Comment: Slider is a little more complicated because of the enhanced markup jQM creates. Here is the fiddle updated with a slider handle background: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/53RGY/1/. For more fun with sliders, have a look at http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/fun-with-the-slider-widget/